# Google maps get latitude and longitude having city name?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get latitude and longitude of a city by providing the API with the city name. It should work for most cities regardless how the user inputs the city.

For example:

City can be 'miami, US' or city can be 'miami, united states'

How do I print its latitude?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can find the code jsfiddled here : http://jsfiddle.net/YphZw/
or below :

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
            var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'miami, us'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
          } else {
            alert("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="search for miami coordinates" />
</body>
</html>
```

If you want more examples for the Javascript API, try this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

The code I wrote is inspired from the *geocoding-simple* sample.

Regards.

EDIT 1:

You can achieve it using an non-official PHP library. Check this example : 
http://www.bradwedell.com/phpgooglemapapi/demos/geocoding.php
(The  code is at the bottom=

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with PHP? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use Google's geocoding service, e.g.,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Miami+FL&sensor=false

That gives you back georeferenced data in a variety of formats (JSON, XML, etc). In any event, the location is definitely in the returned data block.

The API docs are at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: The API Docs' link you gave above and the method you described  is about Google Maps API Web Services and not the Javascript's one.

Comment: Doh! Sorry -- the link to the JS API (very simllar) is on that page though.

Answer (score 2):

**Update per comment below:** Doesn't work after July 2018.

---

This seems needlessly complicated. Here's an example "nearby events" map. It will take `City, State`s, convert them to `latLng` coords, and put markers on a map:

```
// Nearby Events with Google Maps
window.nearbyEventsMap = () => {
    const centerOfUS = {
        lat: 37.09024,
        lng: -95.712891
    }

    // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#nearby_events_map'), {
        center: centerOfUS,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 4
    })

    // Create a marker and set its position.
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    // Filter out duplicate cityStates
    let cityStates = {}
    document.querySelectorAll('.nearby_event_city_state').forEach(event => {
        cityStates[event] = event.innerText
    })

    // `cityState` is in the format of "City, State". It's not picky about state being a word or the abbreviation.
    for (const cityState in cityStates) {
        const location = cityStates[cityState]

        geocoder.geocode({
            address: location
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                const result = results[0].geometry.location
                const lat = result.lat()
                const lng = result.lng()
                const latLng = {
                    lat,
                    lng
                }

                return new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: latLng
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
// /Nearby Events with Google Maps
```

Make sure to include your `<script>` tags.

```
<script src="/dist/js/main.js"></script>

<!-- We're loading this after the main.js script so the callback from main.js will be available to it. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=nearbyEventsMap"></script>
```

StackOverflow please join everyone else and get GitHub markdown with syntax highlighting...

Comment: You need an API key to access this service now

Comment: The API key is included in the `<script>` bit, but Google changes how this stuff works almost annually so he's probably right and it doesn't work. Nowadays I'd suggest using a maintained library so when Google changes how maps works, you just have to do something like `npm install that-library@latest` instead of figuring this out from scratch over and over... :(