# @apollo/client react hook useQuery() data undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I make a fragment gql with react hook apollo client, in network the request is ok but the data doesn't fetch in react... why ? thanks.

my GQL and useQuery :

```
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    import {useQuery} from "@apollo/client";

    const AuthorFragment = {
        entry: gql`
        fragment AuthorFragment on Author {
         ... on User {
           id
         profile {
             pseudo
               picture
               __typename
             }
             __typename
           }
           ... on Guest {
               username
             picture
             __typename
           }
           __typename
     
        }`,
    };

    const MESSAGE_QUERY   = gql`
        query adminMessageSearch($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
         website {
           id
           adminMessageSearch (object: "comments", offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
             meta {
               count
               offset
               limit
              },
              messages {
                id
                content
               contentEditedAt
                createdAt
                status
                ip
                thread {
                  id
                  url
                  pageTitle
                }
                votes {
                  score
                }
                author {
                  ...AuthorFragment
                }
           
             }
             
           }
         }
       }
       ${AuthorFragment.entry}
    `;

    export const useMessageQuery = (offset, limit) => useQuery(MESSAGE_QUERY, {
        variables: {
            offset: offset|| 0, limit: limit || 10,
        },
        fetchPolicy: "network-only" });
```

My react :

```
import React, { useState  } from 'react'
import {useMessageQuery} from "../../graphql/queries/messageQuery";
import Message from "./Message";


export const ListingMessage = () => {

    const {loading,error, data} = useMessageQuery(0, 10);
    if(loading) return 'Loading...';
    if(error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    return (
        <div className="list-disc ">
            <p  > total:  {data.website.adminMessageSearch.meta.count}
                    <br/>
            </p>
       </div> 
    )

}
export default ListingMessage;
```

The data is undefined, but the request graphql that I see in network is ok. I tried to async => await my code useMessageQuery, but seems not to work.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149144/google-maps-get-latitude-and-longitude-having-city-name

Comment: **check this answer** [Google maps get latitude and longitude having city name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149144/google-maps-get-latitude-and-longitude-having-city-name)

Comment: does your hook return anything?

Comment: yes, data hook return anything... but in see in network in chrome graphql result...

Comment: remove `gql` from `entry: gql`

Comment: i try, not work :(

Comment: than ... as usual ... test query (with fragments, variables/exactly the same) in playground before coding

Comment: i have test and it’s work.

Comment: does it work when you move gql fragment into 'main' (`MESSAGE_QUERY`) ? ... you don't have to type `__typename`, apollo adds it internally

Comment: I try without fragment and with union the data is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your query name is `adminMessageSearch` so you can access this by using `data.adminMessageSearch` as you are using `data.website.adminMessageSearch.meta.count` There is no `data.website` which results in getting undefined. So modify

```
return (
        <div className="list-disc ">
            <p  > total:  {data.adminMessageSearch.website.adminMessageSearch.meta.count}
                    <br/>
            </p>
       </div> 
    )
```

Comment: Hi, data is undefined, so data.website (undefined) or data.adminMessageSearch (undefined too).

Comment: Do `console.log(data)` return anything?

Comment: yes, data return anything but when i delete the fragment gql the data return the informations... why ? my fragment has a problem ?